# How to ask one or two turtles (if any are present) to do an action?

Tags: netlogo

The following code finds all patches where there is at least one male and one female present, then on each such patch, has one female hatch an offspring turtle of random gender.

```
turtles-own [ gender] 
to setup 
ask patches [ 
sprout  1 
[set size 0.2 
set color pink 
set gender "female" 

]] 
ask patches [ 
sprout  1 
[set size 0.2 
 set color blue 
 set gender "male" 



]] 

reset-ticks 

end

to-report parents-here?  ;; patch procedure
report any? turtles-here with [gender = "male"]
     and
     any? turtles-here with [gender = "female"]
 end

to go
ask patches with [parents-here?] [
ask one-of turtles-here with [gender = "female"] [
  hatch 1 [
    set gender one-of ["male" "female"]
  ]
 ]
 ]
 tick
 end
```

Instead of asking one female to hatch, I want to ask if one female present ask it to hatch " or " if two females present ask them to hatch ( minmum one and maximum two).
I tried to write it

```
ask n-of 2 turtles-here ............
```

but I had an error said that this patch has only 1 from the turtles

I tried to use ( but also was with error)
also I tried to write

```
ask n-of (1 + random 2 )
```

as minimum and maximum, and it was also wrong.

Thank you in advance

Comment: I didnt get what you mean , ofcourse i didnt mean to be funny, but this is the title I wrote, is there any thing wrong in the title???

Comment: everything is fine. I'm sorry :)

Comment: no problem, I thought some thing is wrong in my title, as I am not native English speaker so I excepect some thing wrong

Answer (score 3):

This is the simplest solution I can think of:

```
let females turtles-here with [gender = "female"]
ask n-of (min list 2 count females) females [
  hatch 1 [
    ...
  ]
]
```

Why `min list 2 count females`? It's a little counterintuitive that you need to use a primitive called `min` when you want a maximum of 2. But the result of `min list 2 ...` is always 2 or smaller. Or if you break it down by cases:

- If `count females` is 0, `min list 2 count females` is also 0.
- If `count females` is 1, `min list 2 count females` is also 1.
- If `count females` is 2 or more, `min list 2 count females` is 2.

which, if I understand correctly, is what you were trying for.

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I tried (min 2 count), but I have an error of (Min excepected this input to be a list , but got a number instead). I serched then and I find (min-n-of) but also give an error.

Comment: oops, updated. `min` expects a list, so to take the min of two numbers it's `min list a b` not just `min a b`